# Memory usage command with syntax similar to the time command

Tags: memory, time, command

What command shows the memory usage of a program, i am looking for a command that is simple to use and has similar syntax to the `time` command.  I am  trying to find the memory usage of a md5 hashing program that is written in C and takes 7 seconds to hash "hello world"  .

I am using the android operating system with busybox installed.

Answer (score 32):

Ironically, `time` might have an answer for you but this time it should be not shell-built-in `time` but standalone one instead:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v uname
Linux
        Command being timed: "uname"
        User time (seconds): 0.00
        System time (seconds): 0.00
        Percent of CPU this job got: 2%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.12
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 896
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 1
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 304
        Voluntary context switches: 3
        Involuntary context switches: 3
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 56
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0
```

It counts MAX RSS though, not VSS, so would it be useful for you or not depends on your very task heavily.

**UPD.**: [Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)' "think" is slightly different but still it's `time`:

```
/usr/bin/time -l /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera
      244.63 real        54.34 user        26.44 sys
 284827648  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
    711407  page reclaims
      1272  page faults
         0  swaps
       155  block input operations
       251  block output operations
     98542  messages sent
     68330  messages received
        16  signals received
       699  voluntary context switches
    468999  involuntary context switches
```

Comment: +1, good to know this. But beware, this is a GNU-specific feature. Does Android include GNU `time(1)`?

Comment: Shell builtin? Neither the `bash` nor `zsh` manpages here mention this. Are you confusing it with `times`?

Comment: @WarrenYoung, `for SH in zsh bash dash; do $SH -c 'echo $0; type time'; done`

— zsh time is a reserved word
— bash time is a shell keyword
— dash time is /usr/bin/time

Comment: @WarrenYoung, and nope, Android doesn't have it by default, *but* since `/usr/bin/time` is built heavily on top of system calls `wait3` or `wait4` (I don't remember exactly), it can be easily put into action there as well.

Comment: By the way macOS time shows maximum memory usage in bytes and Linux in kilobytes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) for this:

```
$ valgrind myprogram arg1 arg2
```

Its output will have a lot of irrelevant stuff, but its heap summary does what you want:

```
==91383== HEAP SUMMARY:
==91383==     in use at exit: 157,643 bytes in 364 blocks
==91383==   total heap usage: 2,999 allocs, 2,635 frees, 306,450 bytes allocated
```

Comment: I do not have `valgrind` but it looks like there is a port for android, i will try and install it.

Comment: @kylek: If you're doing any native CPU software development on Android, you want to have it anyway.